# Magento 2.4.0 Klarna not showing on checkout error code Bad value

Tags: magento2, klarna

On Magento 2.4.0 Klarna is not showing on checkout page.

Error log is `Bad value: order_lines[0].total_tax_amount`.

When I update VAT 25 to 0 it works fine and shows on frontend.

**Here is request JSON body**

```
{
  "purchase_country": "SE",
  "purchase_currency": "SEK",
  "locale": "sv-SE",
  "order_amount": 93000,
  "order_tax_amount": 18600,
  "order_lines": [
    {
      "type": "physical",
      "reference": "car_parts",
      "name": "Car Parts",
      "quantity": 1,
      "total_discount_amount": 0,
      "tax_rate": 2500,
      "total_tax_amount": 16600,
      "unit_price": 83100,
      "total_amount": 83100
    },
    {
      "type": "shipping_fee",
      "reference": "flatrate_flatrate",
      "name": "Shipping & Handling (Fast pris - Fast)",
      "quantity": 1,
      "unit_price": 9900,
      "tax_rate": 2500,
      "total_amount": 9900,
      "total_tax_amount": 2000,
      "total_discount_amount": 0
    }
  ],
  "merchant_urls": {
    "confirmation": "",
    "notification": ""
  }
}
```

How to solve this?